# How to convert reader.Read string to currency format in c#?

Tags: c#

I built the below code, trying to convert reader[BalanceAmt]  to a currency, i.e. $23,456.78. I can't seem to get it to work. It's still returning "23456.782" Any ideas?

```
    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string MyNum = reader["BalanceAmt"].ToString();
                        String.Format("{0:#,###0}", MyNum);
                        BalanceBox.Text = (MyNum);

                    }
```

Comment: `String.Format` returns a string, it doesn't convert what you pass *into* a string.

Comment: Although doing that in a loop seems like the wrong thing. You'll end up only seeing the last value by the time your form repaints.

Comment: Also strings are immutable, the content of `MyNum` could never be changed.

Comment: I changed it to this and it still returns the same incorrect format:         
         while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string MyNum = reader["BalanceAmt"].ToString();
                           
                            BalanceBox.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###0}", MyNum);

                        }

Comment: What is the data type of `BalanceAmt`? If it is a number you should return it as a number. Strings cannot be formatted using format arguments, if you pass a string argument into another string with a format argument the argument is ignored.

Comment: what type does `reader["BalanceAmt"]` return?    double? decimal? string..?

Comment: reader["BalanceAmt"] I believe returns a string

Comment: `reader["BalanceAmt"] I believe returns a string` <= look at the database schema and see how it is stored. If it is stored as a string you should look at changing the schema so its stored as a decimal type. Types exist for a reason and the appropriate type should be used when possible.

Comment: Does this work: `BalanceBox.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###0}", Convert.ToDouble(MyNum));`

Comment: I changed it to this and the "reader["BalanceAmt"]" part is red squigglies  :         int MyNum = reader["BalanceAmt"]
                           
                            BalanceBox.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###0}", MyNum);

Comment: Sjips yours worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @Ja Austin: Mind to vote my answer as the solution?

Comment: done. thank you again.

Comment: @JaAustin not quite, you did not accept the answer that helped you. If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) can help you

Comment: Mong Zhou , Thanks for sharing. Sjips' is now selected as the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use this:

```
BalanceBox.Text = String.Format("{0:#,###0}", Convert.ToDouble(MyNum));
```

Answer (score 2):

If `reader["BalanceAmt"]` returns a `string` then to get your numeric formatting to work, you need to convert it into a number before converting it to currency - i.e.

```
var myNum = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["BalanceAmt"]);
BalanceBox.Text = myNum.ToString("C");
```

Note the `"C"` currency format specifier argument passed into the `decimal.ToString` method - see [MSDN Decimal.ToString Method Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `Convert.ToDecimal` method will throw an exception if `reader["BalanceAmt"]` contains anything that `Convert.ToDecimal` is unable to cope with (non-numeric characters).

You might want to put a `try..catch` around this, or if you don't want an exception to be thrown, use `Decimal.TryParse` inside an `if` check:

```
var balanceAmt = reader["BalanceAmt"];

if (decimal.TryParse(balanceAmt, out var myNum))
{
    BalanceBox.Text = myNum.ToString("C");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (reader.Read())
   {
     BalanceBox.Text = reader["BalanceAmt"].ToString("c");
   }
```

In your code `String.Format("{0:#,###0}", MyNum);` MyNum never changes...only formatted.